# How to make text in a multirow cell go on different lines

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\hline
 & A & B & C  \\
 & & &  &\\
 \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{This is a really long sentence sentence sentence} & 0 & 6 & 230 \\
& 1 & 5 & 195  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make the cell containing "This is a really long sentence sentence sentence" into 2 lines? [image]

Comment: Use a paradox` \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4cm}{This is a really long sentence sentence sentence}} & 0 & 6 & 230 \\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own command and give it width and the text `\breakText{5cm}{text}`, like so :

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\breakText}[2]{%
  \noindent \parbox{#1}{%
    #2
  }%
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
      \hline
      & A & B & C  \\
      & & &  &\\
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{\breakText{5cm}{This is a really long sentence sentence sentence}} & 0 & 6 & 230 \\
      & 1 & 5 & 195  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table2}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```